# Thread set priority doesn't seem to work/go in order? (Java)

Tags: java

I am currently learning about java threads and have recently tried the following code. But the output doesn't seem follow any order even though I have set the priority:

```
class head implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getPriority());
    }
}

class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Thread obj1 = new Thread(new head());
       Thread obj2 = new Thread(new head());
       Thread obj3 = new Thread(new head());
       Thread obj4 = new Thread(new head());
       Thread obj5 = new Thread(new head());
       obj1.setPriority(1);
       obj2.setPriority(2);
       obj3.setPriority(3);
       obj4.setPriority(4);
       obj5.setPriority(5);
       obj1.start();
       obj2.start();
       obj3.start();
       obj4.start();
       obj5.start();
   }
}
```

If anyone can help me solve this issue and make it show up in the proper order (set by the set priority method) it would be much appreciated, thanks for your time.

Comment: I would imagine that by time you call `obj2.start();` `obj1` has already finished

Comment: A thread isn't going to stop running just because a higher priority thread comes along.

Comment: This is not how thread priority works. If you need strict scheduling order you need actual concurrency control methods. What are you really trying to do?